# Is a motor driver required for BO Motors?

Tags: pi-2, driver

I have heard that motor drivers are required for DC Geared motors, or they may get damaged but is a motor driver needed for BO Motors?

Can they be directly connected to the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi and controlled that way?

I am using a Raspberry Pi B Revision 2.

Comment: You need a driver for whatever requires either or both: more than 3.3V or 30-40mA.

Comment: @Nasha, 30..40 mA would already be way out of spec for a single GPIO pin. Max rating is 16 mA.

Comment: @Ghanima Thanks for the info. I knew the limit was very low and couldn't find the exact figure at once. I found 50mA somewhere else, should've double-checked though. Anyway 16 or 50, it's still not enough to drive a motor directly.

Comment: @Nasha, no problem, 50 mA is the rated max total sum of all GPIO pins (which is also not much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BO motor (as far as I can tell from Google) is a DC motor.

A DC motor requires a motor driver.

You need a motor driver board or you need to create your own motor driver from discrete components.

Comment: Thanks!! I had doubts why a motor driver is used that's why I asked it... :)